# Key Controlled Button Menu Cycles Through on Key Hold Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a turn-based styled combat system where the player can cycle down a list of buttons using the up and down keys. Hitting one of these keys modifies a selectedIndex integer to store the last selection if the player leaves the menu. It works almost as intended, hitting down selects the button beneath the current and cycles to the top if the player reaches the bottom; however, when the player holds the down or up keys the buttons quickly cycle in that direction without modifying selectedIndex so if the player selects a new button the selected one jumps to the selected index skipping buttons entirely.

For example lets say selected index is 0, the first button is highlighted. If the player taps down, the second button is highlighted and selected index is 1. If they tap and hold down the down key the selected index becomes 2 and the third button is highlighted for a moment but then the 4th, 5th, and 6th are highlighted in sequence. SelectedIndex remains 2 so if the player taps down again selected index becomes 3 and the 4th button becomes selected even though the player was on the sixth and they hit down.

It's hard to describe without showing it but here is the relevant controller code:

```
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            menu.PrevB();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            menu.NextB();
            Debug.Log(menu.selectedIndex);
        }
```

And the button selection code:

```
public void NextB()
{
    selectedIndex++;
    if (selectedIndex >= attackButtons.Count)
        selectedIndex = 0;

    attackButtons[selectedIndex].Select();
}

public void PrevB()
{
    selectedIndex--;
    if (selectedIndex < 0)
        selectedIndex = attackButtons.Count - 1;

    attackButtons[selectedIndex].Select();
}
```

I would like to implement a hold key to quickly travel down the list of buttons feature in the future but I haven't yet so I'm confused on: why the buttons rapidly select when a key is held without changing the selected index, what could possibly be calling button.Select() when this is the only usage in all my scripts, and why this 'auto scrolling' happens in the same direction even if the up and down keys are reversed (i.e if upArrow calls next button hitting up once will cycle down but holding will auto scroll up).

I'm having a hard time describing the issue in words so I apologize if this sounds confusing. And I use buttons so the mouse can be used if wanted.

Comment: `Input.GetKeyDown()` (which I presume you have in the `Update()` function) does not fire multiple times when being held pressed (only `GetKey()` does that), but only once, so the behavior you describe is not quite matching the code you post. Are you sure you only have that input checker assigned to a single gameObject, and not by accident multiple ones? On a side note, try to be nice to your future self and don't abbreviate as much in a function name like NextB -- you a year from now or the next person helping maintenance may not know instantly what "B" stands for. Good luck!

Comment: I think [navigation options](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/script-SelectableNavigation.html) are the case. Choose `none` and check

Comment: It was the navigation options causing the problem, thank you for the help. And thanks for the advice Philip, you're completely right and I'll change it!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the navigation options on the buttons from Automatic to None as recommended by Hermesis in the comments and it fixed the issue. Thank you for the help!